# Sybase: Rollback on duplicate row error

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

How can I rollback when my insert statement encounters "Attempt to insert duplicate row..." I see Command has been aborted, but my rollback statement does not get executed. In other words, how can I catch this error and perform rollback.

```
begin tran t1

insert into table1 (col1, col2 ) 
select col1, col2
from table2 

if @@error != 0 or @@transtate != 0
        begin
            rollback tran t1
            return
        end
```

Comment: how could you roll it back when nothing got inserted in the 1st place? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest -if tis possible- avoid this condition before insert.

**Way One:** if you want to insert only non-duplicate values:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2) 
select col1, col2 from table2 t2 
 where not exists (select * from table1 t1 where t1.col1 = t2.col1)
```

**Way Two**: if you want to avoid all data insert if it has any duplicate value:

```
if not exists (select * from table t2 
                where col1 in 
              (select col1 from table t1 where t1.col1 = t2.col1))
begin
   insert into table1 (col1, col2) 
   select col1, col2 from table2 t2 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?
I try this on Sybase ASE 15.7

```
select 1 a into #a union all select 1 
select 1 a into #u
create unique index i on #u(a)

begin tran t1
insert #u select * from #a
if @@error != 0 or @@transtate != 0
begin
  rollback tran t1
  print 'rolled back'
end
```

In principle it works:

```
(2 rows affected)
(1 row affected)
Msg 2601, Level 14, State 2:
Server 'CRENG_DEV', Line 6:
Attempt to insert duplicate key row in object '#u00000850012221497' with unique index 'i'
Command has been aborted.
(0 rows affected)
rolled back
```

How are you executing your sql?  Why don't you think it is working?  Are you running it in plain "isql"?  Try that if not.

Answer (score 0):

Probably OP is referring to a mutli-statement transaction (i.e. not his exact example). Sybase ASE will NOT rollback the transaction due to the dupe key error.
For example:

```
Begin tran

Update 1
Insert 2
Insert 3 [duplicate key error here]
Update 2
Insert 4

Commit Tran
```

ONLY insert 3 fails, but all the other items are committed!
After every statement an error check an explicit rollback command is required to backout the whole transaction.

See here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug856.htm